# making background clickable on wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, background

I've recently changed my wordpress theme. On my old theme i could make the background clickable through the admin, but in the new one i can't. Now i know some basic jibba jabba of coding but making a background clickable i still way out of my league.

(not sure if i can post a link to my website here but here is it: http://tijlvos.nl). As an example i've added a picture of one of my favorite actors.